# $f(x)\le g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\le\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that:

$$f(x)\le g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\le\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$

I started with:

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L \implies \forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta(\epsilon,a)|0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = M \implies \forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta_2(\epsilon,a)|0<|x-a|<\delta_2\implies|g(x)-M|<\epsilon$$

If $f(x)\le g(x)$ then $f(x)-g(x)\le0$
I'm trying to find something that proves that $L\le M$. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove the following statement: If $f(x) \leq 0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, then $L \leq 0$.

We can prove $L \leq 0$ by contradiction. So suppose that $L > 0$, then choose $\epsilon = L > 0$, then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that: if $ 0 < |x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < L$, and this means: $-L < f(x) - L < L$ or $f(x) > 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: If $L\le 0$ and $M \le 0$ then $L-M \le 0 \implies L\le M$ right?

Comment: The question also asks if the same is true: $f(x) < g(x)$  then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)< \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$. I think it is, by the same thinking. Do you think too? Thank you so much.